# Creating random directed edges between nodes in nodejs

Tags: node.js, algorithm, graph-theory

Say I have a graph with several nodes. I need to design an algorithm which randomly creates directed edges between nodes while satisfying the following conditions:

- each node has exactly one edge pointing to it
- each node has exactly one edge pointing away from it
- no node points to itself

For example, say my graph had three nodes, the following scenarios would be acceptable:

- Node A points to B, B points to C, C points to A
- Node A points to C, C points to B, B points to A

Does anyone know what the most efficient way of doing this would be? I'm using nodejs btw. For argument's sake, we can say that I am starting with an array containing the names of the nodes.

Thanks

Comment: Does the graph have to be *connected*, or is this also ok for a graph with A,B,C,D as vertices?: A -> C, C -> A, B -> D, D -> B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lets define you have array of vertex: `V = {v}; |V| = N`, now we can shuffle array of vertex by using any random shuffle algorithm.

```
V = [v_1, v_2, v_3,..,v_n]
```

Now we can define `N-1` edges `E`, where `e[i] = (v[i] to v[i + 1])`, and the last vertex will be `(v[N-1] to v[0])`